# What is the longest/shortest tableau proof for this formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I got the following exercise:

> Let $P_1,P_2,P_3$ be propositional variables and $X = ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3) \vee \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$.
>   What is the least\highest amount of steps possible in a tableau proof, where steps are not allowed to be repeated? What is the highest amount if steps can be repeated?

---

I think I get the first question. This is the shortest proof in my opinion:

> $1. \mspace{1em} \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3) \vee \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$
>    $2. \mspace{1em} \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$
>    $3. \mspace{1.7em} ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$

$2$ is contradictory to $3$ so the tree is closed.

---

I have problems with the question about the highest possible steps tough, since in my opinion all I can do starting with $\neg X$ is exactly what I did in the first case, so it would take 3 steps again. Or is it somehow valid in a tableau proof to start with $X$ instead of $\neg X$? Because then it would look like this:

> $1. \mspace{1em} ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3) \vee \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$
>    $2. \mspace{1em} (P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3  \mspace{5em} 3. \mspace{0.5em} \neg ((P_1 \wedge P_2) \wedge P_3)$
>   $4. \mspace{1em} P_1 \wedge P_2  \mspace{6em} 5. \mspace{0.5em} \neg (P_1 \wedge P_2) \mspace{4em} 6. \mspace{0.5em} \neg P_3$
>   $7. \mspace{1em} P_3  \mspace{6em} 8. \mspace{0.5em} \neg P_1  \mspace{4em} 9. \mspace{0.5em} \neg P_2$
>   $10. \mspace{0.5em} P_2$
>   $11. \mspace{0.5em} P_1$

Now every branch is atomar and I can't do anything else.
Is it valid to say that $X$ is a tautology now?

---

If my second answer is correct, then the third question is easy, since I can just repeat one of the steps.
So could anyone tell me if my soultion is correct? In specific I want to know if I am allowed to use the tableau method like I used it to answer the second question.
Thanks in advance!